# Easy secure QEMU network with iptables and WITHOUT a bridge or tap

Tags: linux, iptables, qemu

How do I set up an easy QEMU virtual machine network that I can quickly filter with iptables but not use a bridge or tap interface etc?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok, run qemu from a systemd-nspawn container WITH user isolation (-U flag).
All container processes then will be of format: "vu-containername-number", including qemu.
You can then create iptables filters for this virtual user containerized qemu process and all your traffic to/from container will be taken care of (iptables ... -m owner --uid-owner vu-blah-blah ... -j).
Zero need for any network setups and added security from containerization.